# Show first lines of build log in teamcity email template

Tags: logging, build, teamcity, build-error, email-notifications

I'm new to FTL templates and I want to show the first 100 lines of the build log. I'm given the original script to show the entire build log from the [TC documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Customizing+Notifications), which is this:

```
<#list build.buildLog.messages[1..] as message><#-- skipping the first message (it is a root node)-->
  <#if message.status == "ERROR" || message.status == "FAILURE" > 
    ${message.text}
  </#if>
</#list>
```

What should I add/change to only show the first 100 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this answer only worked for me for the build_fail.ftl template, but changing the index range in build.buildLog.messages to 0..99 helped:

```
<#list build.buildLog.messages[0..99] as message>
```

I posted an answer on this blog and got an answer in my comment: http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/build-timing-and-error-details-teamcity-notifications/